# Can't launch turtlebot_gazebo example, kobuki_description not found

Tags: ros, turtlebot-gazebo, kobuki, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Background : Ubuntu 14.04, ROS indigo, gazebo 2.

I want to launch the example in turtlebot_gazebo:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

The following error appears:

```
... logging to /home/osboxes/.ros/log/8aed81da-765e-11e6-b998-000c29a1f7dd/roslaunch-monmon-6172.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 62, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 687, in main
    process_includes(doc, os.path.dirname(args[0]))
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 246, in process_includes
    filename_spec = eval_text(elt.getAttribute('filename'), {})
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 485, in eval_text
    results.append(handle_extension(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 473, in handle_extension
    return eval_extension("$(%s)" % s)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 66, in eval_extension
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(str, context=substitution_args_context, resolve_anon=False)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 312, in resolve_args
    resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 325, in _resolve_args
    resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 153, in _find
    pkg_path = rp.get_path(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 200, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: kobuki_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I think the important thing is rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: kobuki_description

Please help to solve

And YES, I have tried searching before asking such as:
[this1](http://answers.ros.org/question/122021/xacro-problem-invalid-param-tag-cannot-load-command-parameter-robot_description/)
[this2](http://answers.ros.org/question/193342/broken-kobuki-reference-in-indigo-gazebo/) [this3](http://answers.ros.org/question/62940/rosluanch-turtlebot_bring-minimallaunch/)
But they don't really give solution/fix the problem for me

Any help will be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243419/can%27t-launch-turtlebot_gazebo-example,-kobuki_description-not-found./) by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 582 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my prev [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/243383/rospack-error-package-turtlebot_gazebo-not-found/) , I uninstall and reinstall the turtlebot.

Turns out that I ALSO have to uninstall the kobuki , before reinstalling so

```
sudo apt-get remove turtlebot-*

sudo apt-get remove kobuki-*

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps ros-indigo-turtlebot-interactions ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator ros-indigo-kobuki-ftdi ros-indigo-rocon-remocon ros-indigo-rocon-qt-library ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar-msgs
```

It works for me !!

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0